# Установка пакетов Golang

Tags: golang

пытаюсь установить пакет работы с com портом под Go
наткнулся на проблему:

1. go get <пакет> больше не поддерживается
2. требует использовать go install. При установке выдает сообщение package <имя пакета> is not a main package
   система - linux
   что это может быть и как лечится?

Comment: Исправьте ответ и добавьте информацию - версию Go, название пакета, операционную систему, полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы наверно имеете введу Golang 16й и позднее.. Инициализируйте свою программу через `go mod init` тогда уже после появления файла `go.mod` сможете свободно использовать `go get`

Comment: Спасибо! инициализировал go mod init go.mod и все заработало!!! хорошо быть умным, хотя не будь нас, чайников умным было бы скучно )))